# Smooth contour plot in matplotlib from 3 lists of different size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have 3 lists of different sizes e.g.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Between x=1 and x=2

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
z=[100,200,300,400,500]
y and z are of same length
```

Between x=2 and x=3

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
z=[300, 350, 400, 600, 700]
y and z are of same length
```

So between two values of x, size of y and z are same. But the value of z changes for each y at every interval of x. I would like to generate a plot like this [image: sample plot].

The region between x=1, x=2, will be filled up by the color scale of z. The color bar of z varies from min(z) to max(z) for all the x intervals.

It will be helpful if you please share your suggestion on how to do that.

Thanks,

Comment: So is your data simply a 3D array of dimensions `(n1, n2, n3)`? Or is it such that the data is 2D, but with varying number of elements on each "row"?

Comment: thanks for your reply. its a 3D array and size of each dimension is also constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want seems to be a `contour` plot with a `colorbar`. You can do something like:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, copy=False)
Z = function(X, Y) # I don't know how you are getting the z values from...

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contour(X, Y, Z) # non-filled contour
```

or

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z) # filled contour
```

And to create the `colorbar`:

```
plt.colorbar()
```

[check the documentation for more details and examples.](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)